# Is Service Document mandatory in OData V3?

Tags: odata

Are both of Metadata Document and Service Document mandatory in OData V3?

According V3 core Protocal specification in Chapter 10.1.2, it said that OData services MUST expose a Metadata Document which defines all data exposed by the service.

So I believe Metadata Document is mandatory in OData V3, right?
But what about Service Document in V3?

Thanks for anyone's help,

Answer (score 2):

According to the v3 spec:

> ### 2.2.3.7.1   Service Document
>
> For a client to interact with a data service, it needs to discover the locations of the available collections of resources. AtomPub [RFC5023] defines Service Documents to support this discovery process.
>
> ***The ServiceRoot of a data service MUST identify the Service Document for the data service.***

More importantly, the general concept of a service document is a really important and fundamental REST API concept. REST says that there should be a single entry point that allows a generic hypermedia client to traverse the service. This would be a great time to paraphrase [George Orwell: all REST principles are important but some are more important than others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm). Having a service document will be one of the "more important" principles if you care about generic OData clients like Excel.

Comment: Based on your reply, I think Service Document must be provided by all OData Service(V3), right?

Comment: But I'm a little bit confused one thing: In Chapter 2.2.3.7.2, it says that All data services SHOULD expose a conceptual schema definition language (CSDL) based metadata endpoint that describes the structure and organization of all the resources exposed as HTTP endpoints by a data service.  But on website: [link] (http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol) ,Chapter 10.1.2., it says that OData services MUST expose a Metadata Document which defines all data exposed by the service.

Comment: Have you seen the issue? Seems like there are confict definitions. One is said MUST, another said  SHOULD. So which one is correct?